# How to get low level picture data from CTPicture inside XSSFShapeGroup

Tags: java, apache-poi

Getting [image data from XSSFPicture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658315/reading-images-and-data-from-excel-file-using-poi) is pretty straightforward.

```java
byte[] pictureData = ((XSSFPicture)picture).getPictureData().getData();
```

However, if we [access low level pictures inside XSSFShapeGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760635/get-all-shapes-in-shapegroup) particularly `CTPicture`, how can we retrieve the data from `CTPicture` instances?

Comment: In October 2016, current `apache poi` version was `3.14` or `3.15`. Now in 2021 we are at version `5.0.0` and things have changed. 

Now (since `apache poi 3.17`) there is [ShapeContainer](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ShapeContainer.html) which provides an iterator over all shapes. And `XSSFShapeGroup` also implements `ShapeContainer`. So the usage the low level classes is not more necessary. See my last edit in linked answer.

Comment: thanks for updating the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760635/get-all-shapes-in-shapegroup/39825562#39825562).